# Struts2 radio buttons internationalization

Tags: internationalization, struts2

I have a JSP page that allows user to choose a color using radio button. The available colors are in the following enum

```
enum Colors{RED, BLUE, GREEN};
```

and I'm displaying them using s:radio tag

```
<s:radio name="selectedColor" list="@com.example.Colors@values()" ></s:radio>
```

This works fine and displays the list of all colors present in enum. Now I want to internationalization this list so that the lables with each radio button should be displayed using getText() in listValue

```
<s:radio name="selectedColor" list="@com.example.Colors@values()" listValue="getText(XYZ)"></s:radio>
```

what should I write in place of XYZ to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do the I18N lookup on the business side of things (outside of the view layer) and just pass in a list of value/text objects, or a map of label/value pairs (I usually just use a map to avoid having to create a transfer object).

IIRC the `listValue` attribute would be a property name on the list object; I don't recall if you could actually specify a method like that.